# Stopping subsystems: single CancellationToken vs Stop method

Tags: .net, architecture, .net-core, task-parallel-library

I have simple .net core console application with several long running background services. Services starts when application starts. I want to stop them correctly on user request. Microsoft provided base class for implementing a long running - `BackgroundService`.

```
 public abstract class BackgroundService : IHostedService, IDisposable
  {
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _stoppingCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private Task _executingTask;

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called when the <see cref="T:Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService" /> starts. The implementation should return a task that represents
    /// the lifetime of the long running operation(s) being performed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stoppingToken">Triggered when <see cref="M:Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService.StopAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)" /> is called.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="T:System.Threading.Tasks.Task" /> that represents the long running operations.</returns>
    protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);

    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when the application host is ready to start the service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">Indicates that the start process has been aborted.</param>
    public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      this._executingTask = this.ExecuteAsync(this._stoppingCts.Token);
      if (this._executingTask.IsCompleted)
        return this._executingTask;
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when the application host is performing a graceful shutdown.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">Indicates that the shutdown process should no longer be graceful.</param>
    public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      if (this._executingTask == null)
        return;
      try
      {
        this._stoppingCts.Cancel();
      }
      finally
      {
        Task task = await Task.WhenAny(this._executingTask, Task.Delay(-1, cancellationToken));
      }
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
      this._stoppingCts.Cancel();
    }
```

`BackgroundService` allow to stop service by calling method `StopAsync`.
Also we can implement long running service by this way, using single method and cancelation token:

```
public class LongRunningService
{
    public Task RunAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                // here goes something long running
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {

                }
            },
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
}
```

Both approaches solves my problem. But I can't decide which one is better in terms of code organization and matching class semantics methods. What approach will you choose and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few years of development, I'm ready to answer my own question. Hope this will help anyone else.

If you need to process something during all life of your application, you should choose background service (eg. watchdogs, rating updaters, background email/SMS senders).

If you just need to run any kind of long-running, but the time-limited operation, you should choose `Task.Factory.StartNew` with long-running options.

In most cases, when you create a `.NET Core` app, background services fit most of your cases, because in web apps or background workers usually there's is no need for running long-running tasks from your code manually.